# WATIR nested anchor click not working

Tags: internet-explorer, watir

tabI am opening an IE 9 browser and navigating to a page with nested iframes culminating in an anchor.

If I request the anchor's existance:

```
puts b.frame(:id => "ivuFrm_page0ivu3").frame(:id => "isolatedWorkArea").a(:href => "http://www.bu.edu/link/bin/uiscgi_business.pl").exists?
```

I get `true`

If I try to click:

```
b.frame(:id => "ivuFrm_page0ivu3").frame(:id => "isolatedWorkArea").a(:href => "http://www.bu.edu/link/bin/uiscgi_business.pl").click
```

nothing happens at all even though the link should open a new tab.  I also tried using the anchor's text with the same (non) result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the HTML?  That will help us identify better ways to help.

If there is no error, then the link is being clicked.

Have you tried link instead of a?

```
puts b.frame(:id => "ivuFrm_page0ivu3").frame(:id => "isolatedWorkArea").link(:href => "http://www.bu.edu/link/bin/uiscgi_business.pl").click
```

Also, to add a little clarity to your statements:

```
ivuFrame = b.frame(:id => "ivuFrm_page03ivu3")
WorkArea = ivuFrame.frame (:id => "isolatedWorkArea")

ivuFrame.WorkArea.link(:href => "http://....").click
```

Based on the answer from TestWise ("TestWise inserts this comment just before the link.click: # can't yet handle followFrame."), this either means that TW doesn't support frames or nested frames at all, or that the frame has not yet rendered.  I'd experiment with a wait or when_present statement for the frame itself.

When_present should not create a false response just because an object is nested, but if there were going to be a complication like that I would expect that it would deal with frames.

Comment: Unless the link is dynamically generated (or the frames), when_present should not be necessary.  Can you please provide more HTML?

Comment: In your code above, you would have to set WorkArea = ivuFrame.frame (:id => "isolatedWorkArea") because it is nested.

Comment: The html is generated by SAP and it is way to long to post.  Like I said, .exists? returns true so I know watir is "seeing" the element.

Comment: That IS how it is set (edit time vs. your comment shows I didn't sneak it in either :D)

Comment: Funny thing is the Selenium IDE, Webmetrics, and the TestWise recorders all find the link when recording but fail to find it on playback. <br> TestWise inserts this comment just before the link.click: # can't yet handle followFrame.  <br> I am researching this but not having much luck.

Comment: I get the same result with WebTest.  The recording works swimmingly until I click on the link, then it populates the script with //can't yet handle followFrame.  The frame has rendered as the link is there to be clicked.  Doesn't seem like there is any way to succesfully click it with any of these tools.

Comment: Again, chances are good that this is a problem with the page and not with all of the tools unless this project is cutting edge.  If you're able to link to this page or provide even a larger snip of the code that would be helpful.  Obviously it's something that we're all overlooking either by access or understanding.

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate the time you've expended.  That being said, the page requires a Kerberos login so sending a link wouldn't help.  The html itself is hundreds of lines of SAP obfuscation so I wouldn't be surprised if it is a problem with the page...

Comment: No prob, we've all been in that position, glad to help.  Do you have anything like Firebug for Firefox or Developer Tools for IE?  That may help you track down the frame hierarchy and verify that you're looking at what you think you are.  ALSO, I have had luck specifying a parent DIV or SPAN element in front of some links that magically made them clickable.  Still not sure why.  "frame(:how, what).frame(:how, what).div(:how, what).link(:how, what).click"

Comment: OK thanks.  I've been using Chrome's inspect element - that's how I found the top-level iframe (it doesn't show in view source).  I will try the spans and the divs and let you know how I made out.  Again, thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you're paying attention anymore but...I am using QTP 11 and it is recognizing and clicking on the link.  It refrences it thus:Browser("Home - QPO - QA").Page("Home - QPO - QA").Frame("isolatedWorkArea").Link("BUworks Program Website").Click  I have been trying to find an equivalent to .Page with no luck

Comment: Yes Tim, I'm always watching and waiting ;).  Interesting.  I haven't used QTP, but as obvious as the other elements are to understand - Page doesn't immediately make sense to me either.  I suppose it could be a page element like a DIV (I did a little Googling and this seems plausible).  This adds some credence to my suggestion re: div/span locator for the link, first.  Again, this has helped me out of some trouble spots in the past even though it doesn't quite make sense why it should be required: @browser.frame().frame().div().link().click - obviously pseudocode.